# table caption goes bottom using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-4

Table caption is at the top of the table but when I use a bootstrap class it goes to bottom of the table.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <caption>why?</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I align it to the top of table?

Comment: Same issue with v4.3.1

Answer (score 87, accepted):

That's because bootstrap 4 has default caption css style - `caption-side: bottom`

When you change `caption-side: top;` you will have your caption on the top of the table.

**Update: Bootstrap 5**

You can also put the `<caption>` on the top of the table with `.caption-top`:

```
<table class="table caption-top">
  <caption>List of users</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how to change caption positioning for empty tables? I noticed that when my table is empty, the caption appears at the top of the table instead of the bottom as well.

Comment: Did you tried caption-side: bottom instead of caption-side: top ? You should send me what did you tried so far, I can not guess without some of your code

Comment: Is there a bootstrap classname for this?

Comment: There is no special class name from the bootstrap, you can simply use `<caption></caption>`

Comment: This needs to be declared for the `caption` tag; so in total it's: `caption { caption-side:top; }`

Comment: When I write the CSS instruction for the caption tag, for some reason, it just duplicates the thead of the table. Very weird. I have placed the caption tag just after the table declaration and before the thead declaration.

Comment: For Bootstrap V5.3, the documentation is incorrect. The class ```.caption-top``` must be placed in the ```<caption></caption>``` like ```<caption class="caption-top">Your table caption</caption>``` and not in the ```<table class"table">```. This way, it will work. Otherwise, the caption will be placed on the table bottom.