# How do I get a react-bootstrap-table2 caption to be above the table instead of below it?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I tried using the code in the react-bootstrap-table2 ["Table with caption" example](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Basic%20Table&selectedStory=Table%20with%20caption&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel), but my caption is below the table. I found this answer: ["That's because bootstrap 4 has default caption css style - caption-side: bottom"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48648073/4766), but it's not about react-bootstrap-table2 and it doesn't give an example. Then I found this page: [caption-side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caption-side).

So I created `tables.css`:

```
.top caption {
  caption-side: top;
}
```

I imported it using `import './tables.css';`. And I added the class name to my table:

```
    <BootstrapTable
      className="top"
      bootstrap4={ true }
      caption={ <CaptionElement /> }
      keyField='id'
      data={ data.team.bids }
      columns={ columns }
      striped
      hover />
```

But the caption is still under the table.

How do I get the caption to be above the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `caption` prop on `bootstrap-table-next` works as a plain HTML caption tag.
I created a sample sandbox to play with placement of `caption` for the table.

**Observations**:

> 1. Using the same demo caption element from the storybook, I was able to change placement of caption on top or bottom.
> 2. Note that the `caption` tag renders inside a div with class 'table' and NOT `top`. To achive that, adding below style (with keeping the same JS) would place your caption above/below the table -

```css
table caption {
  caption-side: top;
}
```

Sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-boot-table-caption-placement-1mvql

Comment: That worked! Thank you! How could I have figured out your observation #2 myself?

Comment: You could always inspect the html elements in the browser developer tools.